# how can I connect my image processing application in my android application

Tags: java, python, android, django, image-processing

I have image processing application written in python consists of CRNN model, and I want to take an image from my android application and send it to the image processing and receive back a response from it.
what should I use to make it done.

Comment: I guess the only way to make that work is running python in android:
https://medium.com/@umerfarooq_26378/tools-to-run-python-on-android-9060663972b4

Comment: But it will probably be really hard to find a consistent container for your image to transfer to your python script and getting it back. And it will probably be way slower.

Comment: I would try to find an alternative solution that runs directly in android. Or use Unity instead, because it has a lot of useful image libraries

Comment: Also there are already libraries for Android which can do image recognition for you (if thats what you mean by CRNN model)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a server that deals with the logic (in python) and make the app communicate with it over HTTP requests.

The app would send the image to the server, the server would process it, and then send the output to the app.

Comment: what server do you suggest for me I want it to be easy to deal with it

Comment: I have not made servers with python yet. I know you could use Django or Flask. People tend to prefer Flask because it has a better learning curve for beginners.

If you know how to set up a server in Node or Ruby or anything else you could set up a server in that language and execute python script from it, but I do not recommend it if you can use Flask.

Comment: <3, please, accept the answer if it proves to solve your problem